# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'zip'

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is no problem when I run in python 2.7 but I am getting error when I run in python 3.

Is there something that I need to change in this code.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
poly = mpl.path.Path(zip(listx,listy))
```

error that I am getting is

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'zip'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because in python2 [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returns a list of tuples, which [`mpl.path.Path()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path) happily accepts. In python3, [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), which you must consume. You should be able to do something like:

```
>>> poly = mpl.path.Path(list(zip(listx, listy)))
```

Comment: @bikuser no problem. You can indicate your gratitude by accepting my answer (little checkbox mark).